# How to turn led lights off and on in order when below a certain photovalue?

Tags: sensors, led

I'm making a traffic light simulation with a photoresistor but it's not working properly.
When the photovalue drops below a certain point ( a car comes by) a peeping sound should play for a second and then red light should turn into yellow light and then it should turn green and stay green until the photovalue is back to normal, and then it should turn red again and stay red until the photovalue drops below that point again ( photovalue goes back to normal when the car moves) . I tried different, but did not get the result I was hoping for, the yellow light kept pulsing instead of actually turning off, the green light was turned on but it did not turn off when it was supposed to. In my recent attempt, the green light is not turning off, while red and yellow turn off on. What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?
here's my code for the last attempt.

[image: This is how my circuit looks like, not the most refined but it works as intended ig]

```
byte PhotoInput= 0;
int PhotoValue;
int Pin = 8;
void PlayTone( int freq,  int duration) {
  
delay( duration);
tone ( Pin ,freq, duration ); 


}


int red = 10;
int yellow= 7; 
int green= 5; 



 void setup() {
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode( yellow, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode( green, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  

  PhotoValue = analogRead(PhotoInput);
    ;Serial.println(PhotoValue); 
    delay(50);

    if ( PhotoValue < 100 ) { 
      digitalWrite  (red, HIGH); 
      delay ( 500);
      digitalWrite ( red,LOW);  
      digitalWrite (yellow,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      PlayTone( 100, 50);
        
    
      digitalWrite(green,HIGH);
     digitalWrite ( yellow, LOW);
      
    
    }else if ( PhotoValue > 100) { 
       digitalWrite ( red,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(yellow,LOW);
      digitalWrite(green,LOW);
    
     
    }

   if (PhotoValue > 50 ){ 
    PlayTone( 100, 50);
   }else if ( PhotoValue > 60 )   { 
    PlayTone ( 300, 50); 
   }else if ( PhotoValue > 120 )   { 
    PlayTone ( 600, 50); 
    }else if ( PhotoValue > 160) {
    PlayTone ( 900, 50); 
    }else if ( PhotoValue < 180 )   { 
    PlayTone ( 1100, 50); 
    }else if ( PhotoValue > 200)   { 
    PlayTone ( 1300, 50); 
    }else if ( PhotoValue < 240 )   { 
    PlayTone ( 1600, 50); 
    }else if ( PhotoValue > 260 )   { 
    PlayTone ( 1000, 50); 
    }else if ( PhotoValue < 80 )   { 
    PlayTone ( 600, 50); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Just did that, thanks for pointing it. I'm new to both arduino and this community so I really don't know what's important to mention and what's not.

Comment: What happens if you remove this `delay( duration)` line of code?

Comment: you have no code for `stay green until the photovalue is back to normal`

Comment: do you understand that loop() repeats until the Arduino is reset? .... look at your code closely ... if you cover the sensor then yellow will blink and green will turn on and stay on

Comment: if you want a section of code to run only once for an action, then you have to use flags

Comment: your difficulty arises because of the way that you handle program flow after reading the sensor ... `if (bright) then turn on red LED` is an inflexible way of doing it .... insert a layer of separation between sensing and acting ... use flags ... try `if (bright) then set isBright flag` ... `if (dim) then set isDim flag` ... `if (isDim and isBright) then unset isBright; blink yellow LED` .... this way the yellow LED blinks only once whenever the sensor detects dim light

Comment: I don't really know what flags are in arduino, as said earlier I'm new to this. But assuming from what you said I need to break down the process. It first has to sense the photo value and then it will act based on what follows after the flag for both dim and bright. By creating an if statement for both dim and bright it should become more flexible.  But isn't that harder than actually making and if statement where the yellow led is dependent on the green led. Is there any youtube you recommend on how flags function. @jsotola ?

Comment: `isn't that harder than actually making and if statement where the yellow led is dependent on the green led` ... but what is your green LED dependent on?

Comment: `what flags are in arduino` ... not Arduino ... in any programming language ... a flag is just a variable that you set to a specific value to remember something, such as `bool isBright = true;` ... in real life it could be a note stuck on a fridge or an appointment written in a calendar ... or even a traffic light

Answer (score 0):

To make this simpler I've taken away the buzzer from the code to just concentrate on the lights (from your diagram the buzzer wasn't connected anyway!). I've also tried to keep as much of your code as possible, and just introduce a single flag that is set to true when a car is detected.

When the program first starts `car_detected` is `false` and the red light is switched on in the `setup()` code. When the `PhotoValue` has a low value (<100) then it will set `car_detected` to `true` and go through the sequence of lights, with green finally switching on. Whilst the light input is low, it will see the `car_detected` flag remains `true` and won't perform any further actions.

When the car moves away and the `PhotoValue` is high again (>100) then the flag is cleared, and the red light is switched on again. Again - because of the flag, no further action will take place until the light level changes again.

This is a simplistic example of how you can use a flag to control the state of your program and hopefully will allow you to progress.

```
byte PhotoInput=0;
int PhotoValue;
bool car_detected = false ;

int red = 10;
int yellow= 7; 
int green= 5; 

void setup() {
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT); 

  digitalWrite(red,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(yellow,LOW);
  digitalWrite(green,LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  
  PhotoValue = analogRead(PhotoInput);
  Serial.println(PhotoValue); 

  if ( PhotoValue < 100 ) {
    
    if ( !car_detected ) {
      car_detected = true ;

      digitalWrite(red, HIGH); 
      delay (500);
      digitalWrite(red,LOW);  
      digitalWrite(yellow,HIGH);
      delay(1000);

      digitalWrite(green,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
    }
  }else if ( PhotoValue >= 100) { 
    if ( car_detected ) {
      car_detected = false ;
      digitalWrite(red,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(yellow,LOW);
      digitalWrite(green,LOW);
    }
  }
}
```